# Hibernate Many2Many restict on entity id

Tags: hibernate, hql

In my project i have unidirectional many 2 many association:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
class Product{
  @Enumerated(EnumType.String)
  @Id 
  @Access(AccessType.Property)
  private ProductType type;
  @Column
  private String name;
}
@Entity
class User{
  @Id
  @Access(AccessType.Property)
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
   @ManyToMany 
   private Set<Product> sold = new HashSet<Product>(); 
...
}
```

The tables were generated by Hibernate ,i.e. 3 tables: User, Product, User_Product.
Now, I would like to create a complex HQL query which among other things finds users that sold products with given ProductType (enum being id of Product).
At the beginning i tried:

```
"from User u where u.sold.id =?"
```

but unfortunately i got illegal attemp to dereference collection. 
These 2 work:

```
"select u from User u join u.sold p where p.id =?"

"select u from User u, IN (u.sold) p where p.id =?"
```

but looking at Hibernate generated SQLs i can see that I have 2 joins: user -> user_product -> product. Join to Product is excessive. Since filtering user by sold products is just a begging of complex query i would like to keep the number of joins as small as possible.
Any ideas  how i could rephrase the query.